# Get user id in case Signed Request - Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I know it might be duplicate question but please help. I have created a app and installed it on my Facebook page. My issue when I authenticate it using authentication method I got the user id... But when I go through proper signed request method (i.e. When I login with facebook site only.) I don't get user. how can I get userid in case of signed request that When I login using facebook site.

My signed request.

```
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => '****',
            'secret' => '****',
            'cookie' => true,
        ));

        echo 'User ID :- ' . $user = $facebook->getUser();
        $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($signed_request);
        echo '</pre>';


User ID :- 0
Array (
[algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
[issued_at] => 1372676199
[page] => Array
    (
        [id] => 544896778905441
        [liked] => 
        [admin] => 1
    )

[user] => Array
    (
        [country] => in
        [locale] => en_US
        [age] => Array
            (
                [min] => 21
            )
    )
)
```

How can I get User id.

Comment: You will not get the user id unless the user logged in to your app at least once before.

Comment: I have created a page and I have installed that app on my page.

Comment: Good for you, but doesn’t change what I said before.

Comment: This will no longer work see my answer here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042350/check-if-logged-in-user-has-liked-my-facebook-page/27310661#27310661

Answer (score 0, accepted):

** EDIT **
As of a few months ago (Dec 2014) Facebook no longer allows Like-Gating content. I guess that's why someone is going around placing negative votes and links to their own answers. So the below is no longer valid

There is a difference between getting a signed_request for a user who has authorised an app, which is your first case and getting the user id from a  signed request on a page app. In the second example you can test if a user likes your page, but you can't get the specific user id. They are just interacting with your page - yes they may be logged into Facebook, but they haven't explicitly authorised your app. I presume this is what you mean by "login with Facebook site only"

If you look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/ you will see it states

```
Some fields and values, the user_id and oauth_token for example will only be passed if the user has logged into your app.
```

They may be logged into Facebook, but not have logged in/authorised your app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042350/check-if-logged-in-user-has-liked-my-facebook-page/27310661#27310661

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the instruction on how to decode the signed request here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#parsingsr

OR

You can use the service that I created. It will return decoded signed request :)

```
https://websta.me/fbappservice/parseSignedRequest/<concat signed request here>
```

//angularjs

```
 you may get it via $http.jsonp(url);
```

//jquery // refer to jquery docs on getting jsonp requests

```
$.getJSON( url, {
    format: "json"
  })
```

Comment: how is your service implemented? I am pretty sure, this could work without your service.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I made the change on my answer to provide how I implemented decoding of signedRequest