# Require Facebook like to connect to wireless network

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have received a request from a friend today. He owns a coffee shop and there is a free WIFI access point. Now he wants to require the visitors to like the coffee shop's Facebook page to connect to the network. I don't know how I can do this.
His router is a TP-Link TL-WR940N.

My idea:

- Install DD-WRT
- Redirect to custom login page
- On the custom login page, use Facebook API for Facebook login
- After the user logs in, check if he/she liked the page
- If not, redirect them to the shop's Facebook page

The bad thing is that I can't redirect them back after liking the page.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: *"Now he wants to require the visitors to like the coffee shop's Facebook page to connect to the network."* - I think you may be breaking one of Facebook's rules here.

Comment: That's what my friend asked me to do for him. I've also found this method in other coffee shops in my city.

Comment: See if you can contact the other coffee shops' webmaster(s), see how they do it.

Comment: I tried to contact one of them, they are using some Georgian script (http://freee.gr/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code do you have currently. Please post some code example.

Comment: Thank you! I have found this answer and it can help me to check if the user liked the page. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042350/check-if-logged-in-user-has-liked-my-facebook-page

Comment: No, it can not – because you will not get `user_likes` permission approved in review for such a purpose. Like gating is officially not allowed any more by FB policies – and “but others are doing it” is not a good point to make in any case. You can have people _check in_ to the location though to get WiFi access – and for that, a ready-made solution already exists: https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi

Comment: "my friend asked me to do it" is not a good excuse to do something illegal either.

Comment: Just tell him to use https://www.facebook.com/business/facebook-wifi . It follow all Facebook Policies

Comment: But can I use the Facebook Wifi on this router?

Comment: Well, I think I will do this: I will require them to log in with Facebook and then redirect them to the shop's Facebook page. They will choose if they like it or not.